# ERROR in chunk app [entry] when upgrading to Webpack 4 in Vue.js

Tags: webpack, vue.js, webpack-4

I am faced with an error I don't understand while trying to upgrade a Vue app to use Webpack 4.

Here is how my webpack base configuration looks like;

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')
const webpack = require('webpack')
require('dotenv').config()

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

const createLintingRule = () => ({
  test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
  loader: 'eslint-loader',
  enforce: 'pre',
  include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
  options: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
    emitWarning: !config.dev.showEslintErrorsInOverlay
  }
})

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': process.env
    }),
  ],
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...(config.dev.useEslint ? [createLintingRule()] : []),
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    // prevent webpack from injecting useless setImmediate polyfill because Vue
    // source contains it (although only uses it if it's native).
    setImmediate: false,
    // prevent webpack from injecting mocks to Node native modules
    // that does not make sense for the client
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty'
  }
}
```

I have edited the production file to look like this.

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
  ? require('../config/test.env')
  : require('../config/prod.env')

const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true,
      usePostCSS: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? config.build.devtool : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },

  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        default: false,
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendor",
          chunks: "all"
        }
      }
    },
    concatenateModules: true
  },

  mode: 'production',

  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: {
          warnings: false
        }
      },
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      parallel: true
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css'),
      // Setting the following option to `false` will not extract CSS from codesplit chunks.
      // Their CSS will instead be inserted dynamically with style-loader when the codesplit chunk has been loaded by webpack.
      // It's currently set to `true` because we are seeing that sourcemaps are included in the codesplit bundle as well when it's `false`, 
      // increasing file size: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/1110
      allChunks: true,
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: config.build.productionSourceMap
        ? { safe: true, map: { inline: false } }
        : { safe: true }
    }),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
        ? 'index.html'
        : config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      //chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // keep module.id stable when vendor modules does not change
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),

    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  const CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

The error I am faced with is difficult for me to understand.
I have searched on Google, and have not been able to find a solution.
I have also checked out webpack documentation, but could not get any result to help in this.
What could I be doing wrong?

Here is the error I got.

```
ERROR in chunk app [entry]
static/js/[name].[chunkhash].js
Unexpected token (5:44)
| 
| var REDIRECT = 'redirect_url';
| var TIMEOUT = Object({"GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS":JS ERROR;JS LOG,"npm_config_cache_lock_stale":60000,"npm_config_ham_it_up":,"npm_package_devDependencies_babel_core":6.26.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_chalk":2.3.2,"npm_package_devDependencies_postcss_url":7.3.1,"npm_config_legacy_bundling":,"npm_config_sign_git_tag":,"USER":jioke,"LANGUAGE":en_NG:en,"npm_package_devDependencies_jest":22.4.2,"npm_package_devDependencies_vue_loader":14.2.1,"npm_package_devDependencies_webpack_bundle_analyzer":2.11.1,"npm_package_devDependencies_webpack_cli":2.0.10,"npm_config_user_agent":npm/5.7.1 node/v8.9.4 linux x64,"npm_config_always_auth":,"TEXTDOMAIN":im-config,"XDG_SEAT":seat0,"npm_package_dependencies_vue":2.5.13,"npm_package_devDependencies_optimize_css_assets_webpack_plugin":4.0.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_ora":2.0.0,"npm_config_bin_links":true,"npm_config_key":,"SSH_AGENT_PID":1688,"XDG_SESSION_TYPE":x11,"npm_package_devDependencies_eslint_plugin_node":6.0.1,"npm_package_devDependencies_file_loader":1.1.11,"npm_package_devDependencies_vue_jest":2.1.1,"npm_config_allow_same_version":,"npm_config_description":true,"npm_config_fetch_retries":2,"npm_config_heading":npm,"npm_config_if_present":,"npm_config_init_version":1.0.0,"npm_config_user":1000,"npm_node_execpath":/home/jioke/.nodenv/versions/8.9.4/bin/node,"SHLVL":1,"npm_package_devDependencies_url_loader":1.0.1,"npm_config_prefer_online":,"LESS":-R,"NODENV_HOOK_PATH":/home/jioke/.nodenv/nodenv.d:/usr/local/etc/nodenv.d:/etc/nodenv.d:/usr/lib/nodenv/hooks,"QT4_IM_MODULE":xim,"HOME":/home/jioke,"npm_package_devDependencies_babel_plugin_dynamic_import_node":1.2.0,"npm_config_force":,"DESKTOP_SESSION":ubuntu,"npm_config_only":,"npm_config_read_only":,"ZSH":/home/jioke/.oh-my-zsh,"LSCOLORS":Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad,"npm_package_engines_node":>= 8.9.4,"npm_config_cache_min":10,"npm_config_init_license":ISC,"GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE":ubuntu,"PAGER":less,"GTK_MODULES":gail:atk-bridge,"XDG_SEAT_PATH":/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0,"npm_package_devDependencies_eslint_loader":2.0.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_node_notifier":5.2.1,"npm_package_devDependencies_shelljs":0.8.1,"npm_config_editor":vi,"npm_config_rollback":true,"npm_config_tag_version_prefix":v,"LC_CTYPE":en_NG,"npm_package_devDependencies_rimraf":2.6.2,"npm_config_cache_max":Infinity,"npm_config_timing":,"npm_config_userconfig":/home/jioke/.npmrc,"NODENV_VERSION":8.9.4,"DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS":unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,"npm_package_dependencies_dotenv":5.0.1,"npm_package_dependencies_moment":2.21.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_jest_serializer_vue":0.3.0,"npm_config_engine_strict":,"npm_config_init_author_name":,"npm_config_init_author_url":,"npm_config_tmp":/tmp,"COLORTERM":truecolor,"LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI":qemu:///system,"npm_package_description":A Kudy.io User Interface Design Project,"npm_package_dependencies_vue_session":1.0.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_babel_loader":7.1.4,"npm_config_depth":Infinity,"npm_config_package_lock_only":,"npm_config_save_dev":,"npm_config_usage":,"npm_package_devDependencies_nightwatch":0.9.20,"npm_package_readmeFilename":README.md,"npm_config_metrics_registry":https://registry.npmjs.org/,"npm_config_cafile":,"npm_config_otp":,"npm_config_package_lock":true,"npm_config_progress":true,"npm_config_https_proxy":,"npm_config_save_prod":,"MANDATORY_PATH":/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path,"IM_CONFIG_PHASE":2,"npm_package_scripts_dev":webpack-dev-server --mode development --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js,"npm_package_devDependencies_babel_jest":22.4.1,"npm_config_cidr":,"npm_config_onload_script":,"npm_config_sso_type":oauth,"LOGNAME":jioke,"GTK_IM_MODULE":ibus,"npm_package_dependencies_request":2.83.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_eslint_plugin_import":2.9.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_vue_template_compiler":2.5.13,"npm_config_rebuild_bundle":true,"npm_config_save_bundle":,"npm_config_shell":/usr/bin/zsh,"WINDOWID":44040198,"npm_package_private":true,"npm_package_devDependencies_autoprefixer":8.1.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_babel_register":6.26.0,"npm_config_dry_run":,"npm_config_prefix":/home/jioke/.nodenv/versions/8.9.4,"DEFAULTS_PATH":/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path,"npm_package_scripts_lint":eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit test/e2e/specs,"npm_package_devDependencies_eslint_import_resolver_webpack":0.8.4,"npm_package_devDependencies_postcss_import":11.1.0,"npm_config_scope":,"npm_config_browser":,"npm_config_cache_lock_wait":10000,"npm_config_ignore_prepublish":,"npm_config_registry":https://registry.npmjs.org/,"npm_config_save_optional":,"npm_config_searchopts":,"npm_config_versions":,"XDG_SESSION_ID":c2,"TERM":xterm-256color,"npm_package_dependencies_path":0.12.7,"npm_package_devDependencies_selenium_server":3.10.0,"npm_config_cache":/home/jioke/.npm,"npm_config_proxy":,"npm_config_send_metrics":,"RBENV_SHELL":zsh,"NODENV_ROOT":/home/jioke/.nodenv,"GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID":this-is-deprecated,"npm_package_scripts_start":npm run dev,"npm_package_devDependencies_babel_plugin_transform_es2015_modules_commonjs":6.26.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_html_webpack_plugin":3.0.6,"npm_config_global_style":,"npm_config_ignore_scripts":,"npm_config_version":,"GTK2_MODULES":overlay-scrollbar,"npm_package_author_email":engineering@altalabs.io,"npm_package_dependencies_axios":0.18.0,"npm_package_dependencies_dotenv_webpack":1.5.5,"npm_package_devDependencies_postcss_loader":2.1.1,"npm_config_local_address":,"npm_config_viewer":man,"npm_config_node_gyp":/home/jioke/.nodenv/versions/8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js,"PATH":/home/jioke/.nodenv/versions/8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/jioke/lab/altalabs/ui/node_modules/.bin:/home/jioke/.nodenv/versions/8.9.4/bin:/home/jioke/.nodenv/libexec:/home/jioke/.nodenv/plugins/nodenv-update/bin:/home/jioke/.nodenv/plugins/node-build/bin:/home/jioke/.yarn/bin:/home/jioke/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:/home/jioke/.nodenv/shims:/home/jioke/.nodenv/bin:/home/jioke/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/jioke/.rbenv/shims:/home/jioke/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin,"GDM_LANG":en_US,"SESSION_MANAGER":local/jioke-K53E:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1550,unix/jioke-K53E:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1550,"npm_package_name":kudyio,"npm_config_prefer_offline":,"NODE":/home/jioke/.nodenv/versions/8.9.4/bin/node,"XDG_MENU_PREFIX":gnome-,"S_COLORS":auto,"XDG_RUNTIME_DIR":/run/user/1000,"XDG_SESSION_PATH":/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0,"npm_package_devDependencies_eslint_config_airbnb_base":12.1.0,"npm_config_color":true,"DISPLAY"::0,"npm_package_devDependencies_webpack_merge":4.1.2,"npm_config_fetch_retry_mintimeout":10000,"npm_config_maxsockets":50,"npm_config_offline":,"npm_config_sso_poll_frequency":500,"LANG":en_NG,"XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP":ubuntu:GNOME,"npm_package_devDependencies_eslint":4.18.2,"npm_package_devDependencies_webpack":4.1.1,"npm_config_umask":0022,"LS_COLORS":rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:,"XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP":ubuntu,"XMODIFIERS":@im=ibus,"XAUTHORITY":/home/jioke/.Xauthority,"npm_package_scripts_e2e":node test/e2e/runner.js,"npm_package_devDependencies_babel_helper_vue_jsx_merge_props":2.0.3,"npm_package_devDependencies_copy_webpack_plugin":4.5.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_cross_spawn":6.0.5,"npm_package_devDependencies_portfinder":1.0.13,"npm_package_browserslist_0":> 1%,"npm_package_gitHead":af9ba67ec99075571f74994a3a11fcd297e6b604,"npm_config_fetch_retry_maxtimeout":60000,"npm_config_loglevel":notice,"npm_config_logs_max":10,"npm_config_message":%s,"npm_lifecycle_script":node build/build.js,"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh,"XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR":/var/lib/lightdm-data/jioke,"npm_package_scripts_unit":jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage,"npm_package_scripts_test":npm run unit && npm run e2e,"npm_package_devDependencies_webpack_dev_server":3.1.0,"npm_package_browserslist_1":last 2 versions,"npm_config_ca":,"npm_config_cert":,"npm_config_global":,"npm_config_link":,"SHELL":/usr/bin/zsh,"npm_package_version":1.0.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_eslint_friendly_formatter":3.0.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_semver":5.5.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_webpack_dev_middleware":3.0.1,"npm_package_browserslist_2":not ie <= 8,"npm_config_access":,"npm_config_also":,"npm_config_save":true,"npm_config_unicode":,"npm_lifecycle_event":build,"QT_ACCESSIBILITY":1,"GDMSESSION":ubuntu,"npm_package_scripts_build":node build/build.js,"npm_config_argv":{"remain":[],"cooked":["run","build"],"original":["run","build"]},"npm_config_long":,"npm_config_production":,"npm_config_searchlimit":20,"npm_config_unsafe_perm":true,"npm_package_dependencies_lodash":4.17.5,"npm_config_auth_type":legacy,"npm_config_node_version":8.9.4,"npm_config_tag":latest,"npm_package_dependencies_vue_router":3.0.1,"npm_package_devDependencies_uglifyjs_webpack_plugin":1.2.2,"npm_config_git_tag_version":true,"npm_config_commit_hooks":true,"npm_config_script_shell":,"npm_config_shrinkwrap":true,"TEXTDOMAINDIR":/usr/share/locale/,"GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT":stderr,"npm_config_fetch_retry_factor":10,"npm_config_save_exact":,"npm_config_strict_ssl":true,"XDG_VTNR":7,"NODENV_SHELL":zsh,"QT_IM_MODULE":ibus,"npm_package_devDependencies_babel_preset_stage_2":6.24.1,"npm_config_dev":,"npm_config_globalconfig":/home/jioke/.nodenv/versions/8.9.4/etc/npmrc,"npm_config_init_module":/home/jioke/.npm-init.js,"npm_config_parseable":,"PWD":/home/jioke/lab/altalabs/ui,"npm_config_globalignorefile":/home/jioke/.nodenv/versions/8.9.4/etc/npmignore,"npm_execpath":/home/jioke/.nodenv/versions/8.9.4/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js,"CLUTTER_IM_MODULE":xim,"XDG_DATA_DIRS":/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/var/lib/snapd/desktop,"XDG_CONFIG_DIRS":/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg,"npm_package_author_name":Alta Labs,"npm_package_devDependencies_css_loader":0.28.10,"npm_package_devDependencies_vue_style_loader":4.0.2,"npm_package_engines_npm":>= 5.7.1,"npm_config_cache_lock_retries":10,"npm_config_searchstaleness":900,"NODENV_DIR":/home/jioke/lab/altalabs/ui,"npm_package_devDependencies_babel_preset_env":1.6.1,"npm_package_devDependencies_chromedriver":2.36.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_eslint_plugin_vue":4.3.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_extract_text_webpack_plugin":4.0.0-beta.0,"npm_config_node_options":,"npm_config_save_prefix":^,"npm_config_scripts_prepend_node_path":warn-only,"npm_package_devDependencies_babel_eslint":8.2.2,"npm_package_devDependencies_babel_plugin_transform_runtime":6.23.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_babel_plugin_transform_vue_jsx":3.7.0,"npm_config_group":1000,"npm_config_init_author_email":,"npm_config_searchexclude":,"VTE_VERSION":4804,"npm_package_devDependencies_babel_plugin_syntax_jsx":6.18.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_eslint_plugin_promise":3.6.0,"npm_package_devDependencies_friendly_errors_webpack_plugin":1.6.1,"npm_config_git":git,"npm_config_optional":true,"npm_config_json":,"INIT_CWD":/home/jioke/lab/altalabs/ui,"NODE_ENV":"production"}).TIMEOUT;
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you cleared your node_modules, package.lock and reinstalled all modules?

Comment: @John yes I have.

Comment: Hi, could you post your error message in the initial thread so we can figure out what's wrong?

Comment: @EvenAndréStensberg done that :)

Comment: Can you try to follow this guide? https://gist.github.com/gricard/e8057f7de1029f9036a990af95c62ba8

Comment: @EvenAndréStensberg I used that earlier, it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to rename `[chunkhash]` to `[hash]` in your webpack file